# automatically exit server when bash is closed

Tags: debian, logout

I have Debian.
I have created user and add automatic script which launches bash each time user logs in. But when he is logged out, first bash is stopped, then he needs to exit once more:

```
blog@debian:/var/web/Blog/css$ exit
$ exit
```

So exit should be put two times((( What should I add to jump from it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just running bash in the script on login, you should instead `exec` bash - this will replace the initial process with the new bash process so that there is only one shell to exit on logout.

```
#!/bin/sh
...
exec bash
```

Comment: How to automatically launch bash when user does sudo?